# JQuery replaceWith / toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a 3 by 3 grid of some data visuals. Whenever a user hovers over a tile in the grid I want to have the content change to render a solid background color with some text, and then when the user hovers off the tile I want it to revert back to the gauge. I've tried a few different ways to do this including .effect but typically had issues when hiding/showing content etc. I'm getting the desired replacement effect using the replaceWith function below, however even when I attempt to have a second function doing another replaceWith I can not get it to revert back to my gauge. Any suggestions how to modify my function or a different JQuery function to try?

```
   $('#fooChartButton').hover(function () {
        $('#fooChartButton').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#fooChartButton').replaceWith('<a href="#" id="fooReplaceChartButton"><div class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns replaceGaugeArea"><div>foo<br />Chart</div></div></a>');
            $('#fooReplaceChartButton').show().fadeIn('fast');
        });
});
```

Row HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <a href="#" id="foo1ChartButton">
        <div class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns modalGaugeArea">
            <span class=foo1Title">foo1</span>
            <div id="foo1Gauge" class="gaugeContainer"></div>
            <span class="foo1Dialogue">foo1</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="foo2ChartButton">
        <div class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns modalGaugeArea">
            <span class="foo2Title">foo2</span>
            <div id="foo2tGauge" class="gaugeContainer"></div>
            <span class="foo2Dialogue">foo2</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="foo3ChartButton">
        <div class="large-3 large-offset-1 columns modalGaugeArea">
            <span class="foo3Title">foo3</span>
            <div id="foo3Gauge" class="gaugeContainer"></div>
            <span class="foo3Dialogue">foo3 Activity</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Each tile CSS:

```
.modalGaugeArea {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #808080;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #808080;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a good application for a pure CSS solution -- would you be interested in that? (summary: add a `:hover` rule that unhides an element absolutely positioned to 100% width/height, covering the tile)

Comment: Could you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I added the HTML and CSS above. I wouldn't be opposed to pure css I did run into trouble when using :hover in getting over the gauge visual, but definitely willing to try it.

I will attempt to add a Fiddle, I'm using some extra libraries so let me give that a try.

Comment: here's a basic pure CSS fiddle (no effects yet) http://jsfiddle.net/2KZH8/1/ . You can easily combine this with `.animate()` for some extra jQuery fun, or use CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with one of the gauges. http://jsfiddle.net/X9sae/6/

Comment: The CSS almost works, however it ends up cutting off the right side of my gauge box which ends up standing out. Is there anyway you suggest of handling that? I am currently messing with the overflow etc, the float moves it's position in the grid, when I move it back it cuts off the right side.